# Fatal error tengo un error y quisiera vuestra colavoración

Tags: javascript, php, mvc

Tengo un error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function FETCH_ASSOC() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoManej\Controller\grafico.C.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoManejoDeArchivosAlcaldiaIquira\Controller\grafico.C.php on line 17

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hago var_dum y si me trae los datos de la consulta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la consulta sql

Comment: Hola. Por favor, el código debe ir como texto. Pulsa en [edit] y cambia las capturas de imagen por el texto, basta un simple copiar / pegar.

Comment: Hola FERNEY, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta,

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.